# Computing EField around a point in a ring

Tags: c#, vb.net, math, physics

I am trying to write code to compute the Efield on a point P in both the x and y direction, from a charged ring.

```
double y_eField = (_ke_value * _dq * (Sin_angle) / (Math.Pow(r, r)));
```

Problem I am having is the code seems to follow the equation as given but the result it outputs is not correct at all. Anyone able to help please? I appreciate the help.

Comment: Are you breaking the ring up into little pieces, `_dq` and essentially summing them with different r's and angles? Michael is quite right about the `Pow(r, r)` part, but this isn't a trivial thing to calculate. You can get a closed form for positions lying on the axis that passes through the center of the ring perpendicular to the area of the ring, but arbitrary points will basically require numerically evaluating an integral over discretized amounts of charge around the ring as far as I can tell.

Comment: I did change the Pow(r,r) mistake, and yes, _dq is my charge at point, and yes, the angles are different for each point on the ring. Could you please explain what you mean by getting a closed form for positions lying on the axis?

Comment: You can explicitly do the integral for the case I said rather than approximating it numerically, like you would need for most other points. The resulting equation is `E = q*z*k_e/(z^2 + R^2)^(3/2)` in the z direction. Derivations of this area all over the web if you google correctly. Here, z is the distance away from the center of the circle along the axis perpendicular to the area of the ring. Basically, you're able to integrate it because of the symmetry. Notice that for z=0, E=0, which also makes sense by symmetry.

Answer (score 1):

This might be more applicable for the [Physics Stack Exchange](https://physics.stackexchange.com/).  That said, are you sure you want to raise r to the power of r (as implied by `Math.pow(r, r)`)?  I suspect maybe you want r squared?  If that's the case you could use `Math.pow(r, 2)` or simply `r*r`.

Comment: Thanks for catching that error. I did change it out but that the answer is still not correct. I figure since the problem is likely code related, this would be the best place for it but I may be wrong.